# browser: display only the sections containing search results

Tags: browser, find

While viewing a web page, I'd like to issue a search command and have everything on the page disappear except the areas of the page that contain the search term.

Most text editors can show only the lines containing a search term.  Sometimes I move the page source to a text editor to do that.

Perhaps a Firefox Greasemonkey script? Start by displaying just the sections that contain the text (paragraph, div, whatever) with some kind of control to expand the scope one notch at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Selected Text Highlighter](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/55148) Greasemonkey script should do the job.

Comment: Sorry my reference to Safari/find was a distraction (and has been removed).  I want to see *only* the sections containing the search term.  I'm going to try coming up with a couple of screen shots to help explain.  Thanks for the suggestion.